# javascript nodejs if statements being invoked in unexpected order

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

Given the code below, i'm assuming i'm running into an async issue.

```
exports.existingCheck = function (req, res, next) {

    var query = [],
        message = [],
        userObj = {},
        i, body = req.body;

    if(body.displayName){
        var regex = new RegExp(["^", body.displayName, "$"].join(""), "i");
    };

    if(req.user){
        var userObj = req.user;
    }

    if (body.displayName !== userObj.displayName) {
        console.log('body n no match')
        query.push({
            displayName: regex
        });
    }
    if (body.email !== userObj.email) {
        console.log('body e no match')

        query.push({
            email: body.email
        });
    }
    console.log('query pre ', query)

    if (query.length) {
        console.log('query init ', query)
        //find a match for email or display name and send appropriate error message;
        User.find({
                $or: query
            },
            function (err, existing) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('register er ', err)
                }
                if (existing.length) {

                    for (i = 0; i < existing.length; i++) {

                        var conditional1 = false, conditional2 = false;

                        console.log('conditional1 init ', conditional1)

                        if(body.displayName && (userObj._id !== existing[i]._id)){
                            conditional1 = body.displayName.toLowerCase() === existing[i].displayName.toLowerCase();
                        };

                        console.log('conditional1 after ', conditional1)

                        if(body.email && (userObj._id !== existing[i]._id)){
                            conditional2 = body.email.toLowerCase() === existing[i].email.toLowerCase();
                        }

                        if (conditional2) {
                            message.push('Email is not unique.');
                        }

                        if (conditional1) {
                            message.push('Display name has already been taken.');
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    console.log('message check ', message)
    if (message.length) {
        return res.status(409).send({
            'message': message
        });
    }
    console.log('next')
    next();
};
```

the code below results in the console.logS firing in this order:

```
body n no match
query pre  [ { displayName: /^bobohead$/i } ]
query init  [ { displayName: /^bobohead$/i } ]
message check  []
next
conditional1 init  false
conditional1 after  true
```

With the problem being that the conditionals are not receiving their values until after the message check and next() are invoked.

I thought that the if statements were blocking code and that one would wait for the other to be fired.

I'm assuming i'll need to add an else statement to call a function that invokes the message check and next() & to invoke that same function at the end of the initial if statement.

do I also need to ensure i invoke next() within an else statement, to ensure that it is not called before the return in the message check has processed? :

```
console.log('message check ', message)
if (message.length) {
    return res.status(409).send({
        'message': message
    });
}
else{
  console.log('next')
  next();
 }
};
```

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? is it that `console.log` always logs `{ displayName: /^bobohead$/i }`?

Comment: No, that the conditionals are not invoked before the next() or message / error check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like your call to `User.find` is asynchronous; thus, the code inside the callback function you pass gets executed after the containing `existingCheck` function returns.

If you want something to happen only after the `User.find` call finishes, you'll have to put that code inside the callback, too.

Note that you can't return a value from the enclosing function from inside a callback. After all, by the time the callback executes, the enclosing function has already finished. If you want to return an asynchronous value, return a `Promise` to it instead (or pass the value to a callback).